# Stuck with SQL statement again. Error: "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to make the following SQL server statement to work, but I get this error: "Invalid column name 'bfg'."

```
WITH valDiff AS (
 SELECT 

  CASE 
   WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
   ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
  END AS bfg,

 datediff(second,
  CASE 
   WHEN [InTime] >= @in THEN [InTime]
   ELSE @in 
  END,
  CASE  
   WHEN bfg <= @out THEN bfg  
  ELSE @out 
 END) 

 AS v1 FROM [MyTable] 

 WHERE 
 AND [InTime] <= @out 
 AND  bfg >= @in

) SELECT SUM(v1) FROM valDiff;
```

In a nutshell, the first CASE with DATEADD should set 'bfg' as min(OutTime, InTime + 7 days). The second part or DATEDIFF should calculate the time difference in seconds between the InTime field and 'bfg' calculated above, if they fall within the @in and @out time frame.

I wish I knew SQL better..... How do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the alias `bfg` after its creation within the same query. The strong need to do this usually signifies the need to throw the code into a JOIN clause so that you can reference it from an alias.

### INNER JOIN solution

This is the "Pretty" option. Join on your table again.

```
SELECT 
  T2.bfg,
  datediff(second,
    CASE WHEN [InTime] >= @in THEN [InTime] ELSE @in END,
    CASE WHEN T2.bfg <= @out THEN T2.bfg ELSE @out END) 
  AS v1 
FROM 
  [MyTable] as T1
  inner join
  ( SELECT MyTableID,
     CASE 
      WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
      ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
     END AS bfg
    FROM
     [MyTable]
  ) as T2 on T2.MyTableID = T1.MyTableID 
WHERE 
  [InTime] <= @out 
  AND  T2.bfg >= @in
```

### VIEW Method

You can create a view, then select from it instead.

Do this once:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView as
SELECT
 CASE 
   WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
   ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
  END AS bfg,
 *
FROM
 [MyTable]
```

Then, your queries would look like this:

```
WITH valDiff AS (
 SELECT 
  bfg,
  datediff(second,
   CASE 
    WHEN [InTime] >= @in THEN [InTime]
    ELSE @in 
   END,
   CASE  
    WHEN bfg <= @out THEN bfg  
   ELSE @out 
  END) AS v1 
FROM [MyView] 
WHERE 
 [InTime] <= @out 
 AND  bfg >= @in
) SELECT SUM(v1) FROM valDiff;
```

### Ugly Solution

This is simply a matter of copy pasting your Case Statement to 3 locations.

**You have to replace `bfg` in your WHERE clause (and other locations) with the following:**

```
CASE 
 WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
 ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
END
```

**So that your entire code reads:**

```
WITH valDiff AS (
 SELECT 

  CASE 
   WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
   ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
  END AS bfg,

 datediff(second,
  CASE 
   WHEN [InTime] >= @in THEN [InTime]
   ELSE @in 
  END,
  CASE  
   WHEN 
     CASE WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
     ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
     END 
   <= @out THEN 
     CASE 
     WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
     ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
     END
  ELSE @out 
 END) 

 AS v1 FROM [MyTable] 

 WHERE 
 [InTime] <= @out 
 AND  CASE 
   WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
   ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
  END >= @in

) SELECT SUM(v1) FROM valDiff;
```

Comment: But there's no way to move that CASE check with 'bfg' out, is there? I'm just trying to up the efficiency....

Comment: Wow, thanks dude! Let me test it and then I'll mark it as the answer. Much appreciated.... Why don't I know SQL like that :)

Comment: Another valid option would be to make a `view` which would contain that BFG value as a column, then you can select from the view with this query without any JOIN or nasty bfg-case statements at all

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you make a view?

Comment: Edited to show the basics. A view is almost exactly like a table -- in fact, you use it just like you would a table. however, you can do some processing in a view that you can't do in a table. You can also do some joins and stuff inside a view. Sometimes it is useful in acting as an interface to some complex tables. However, the code in a view gets executed each time you select from it, so try not to abuse it!

Comment: Thanks. Just to add more details. I may have up to 90 of those SELECT SUM statments (my whole first post) in one SQL query. So you see, why I'm looking for efficiency. Will view help in that case? I may need to create 30 different views in that case (one used for 3 intrinsic select clauses.)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the version with the `inner join` may be fastest; however, it might be the same as the view. With that said, you may consider opening another question regarding whether or not it is actually necessary to do 90 of those statements. There might be a better way. good luck

Comment: I seem to be having problem with your INNER JOIN solution.... InTime, OutTime and MyTableID are invalid in the internal SELECT that is joined into.

Comment: Are InTime, OutTime, and MyTableId all columns within MyTable?

Comment: Yes, except MyTableID is ID, but I did change it. This part looks weird: select MyTableID,     CASE       WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]      ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime])      END AS bfg

Comment: Wow, I'm really sorry about that. I forgot the FROM clause of the subquery select. The subquery should be: `SELECT MyTableID,
     CASE 
      WHEN DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) <= [OutTime] THEN [OutTime]
      ELSE DATEADD(second, 604800, [InTime]) 
     END AS bfg
    FROM
     [MyTable]`

Comment: Thanks again. It did work without an error but the result is not what I expected from my original query and I don't have enough knowledge in SQL to debug it any further... I also tried your Ugly Solution and it didn't work either. I get this error: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected."

Comment: An alternative to the view would be to use an inner query: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT CASE ... END AS bfg, * FROM [MyTable]) [MyTable2]`